# "hints" formatted query output using oracle jdbc driver

Tags: oracle, jdbc, oracle-sqldeveloper, query-hints, sqlcl

Is it possible to get "hints" formatted query output using oracle jdbc driver?

example query

```
Select /*insert*/ * from sample_table
```

or

```
Select /*html*/ * from sample_table
```

looks like the stmt.executeQuer is just ignoring formatting "hints" and only return Select * results

```
        try {
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select /*insert*/ * from sample_table where ID = 1");

            while (rs.next()) {
                inserts.add(rs.getString(1));                    
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            log.error("SQL Error", e);
        } finally {
```

**UPD:** As mentioned in the comments the `/*insert*/` "hint" is specific to the SQL Developer and SQLcl clients.

I was able to get the query formatted output from SQLcl client
[image]

The eventual goal is to get formatted query output from Java code.
So re-phrasing the question: how to run query and get output through **SQLcl** using java ?

Comment: Well your example `/*insert*/` is a *comment* - not a *hint*.  And *comments* are ignored. But what is the question?

Comment: @Marmite Bomber it's not comment. please see https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/oracle-sql-developer/9781785281273/ch02s10.html. You can try query in SQL Developer

Comment: we implemented that feature on top of the driver in our client tools (sqldev, sqlcl)

Comment: Those hints (and the `set sqlfomat` version/enhancement) are specific to the SQL Developer and SQLcl clients. They aren't part of SQL so don't mean anything to JDBC or anything else - they are treated as comments everywhere else.